# Add extra static tableview to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with a dynamic `tableView`. Now, I want to add a second `tableview` as subview to my `UITableViewController` on button click, but I want to design this static `tableView` using `storyboard`. So I added another `UITableViewController` and changed the class of the `tableView` to my custom class. But when I instantiate it on my firs TVC, it doesn't load the one from storyboard. I think it just instantiates a new object of my custom class but not the one on the `storyboard` file. And I can't connect the outlet of the `tableView` to my first TVC, it doesn't let me.

So I guess my option here would be to implement a new `UITableViewController` and add it as subview, instead of just adding the table, right? I just thought I didn't need another `UITableViewController` and could just use the `tableview` but I guess I'm wrong.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

This code works fine, I'm just wondering if this is the right approach.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Treinamento" bundle:nil];
TabRelTableView *tabRelatorio = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabRelTableView"];
tabRelatorio.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 38, 320, 466);
[self addChildViewController:tabRelatorio];
[self.view addSubview:tabRelatorio.tableView];
```

TabRelTableView is a `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of view controller containment? This way you can have a custom controller with dynamic table view as well as storyboard-designed static tableView. Then you can switch between dynamic and static ones based on your needs.

Comment: Well, thanks. But my dynamic `tableview` is ready, I don't want to change the implementation, besides, the button to show the other table is going to be on this table, and the other won't take the whole screen, the first one will still be showing. So I guess I want to keep my `UITableViewController`.